# Slow queries when putting files into "LIVE" environment

Tags: asp.net, performance, oracle, architecture

Here's the situation...

We have a local development server at Location A where we build all our aspx pages. Our databases are located at Location A also.

When testing our files on the development server our queries run quickly most under 1 second.

We have just move our files up to our live server which is located at Location B (databases are still at Location A) and the queries now take anywhere between 5-10 times longer than the development server.  Location A is in East Anglia, Location B is in London roughly 100 miles apart.

Also on both dev and live server the first query that is run takes a lot longer than the rest of the queries thereafter.

Any ideas what may be causing the slowness?

**EDIT**

I've turned tracing on for a few of the pages and it seems that End Load is taking the longest of all the methods however I'm unsure why

I also do not have access to our external server to be able to install SSMS or Oracle developer on there to test any queries unfortunately.

Comment: Where is Location B in relation to Location A - could it be a network speed issue rather than a query time issue?

Comment: You could do a couple of things, firstly turning on Tracing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx at Location B to show execution times of requests which will help you pin point slow methods; secondly if you can get SSMS onto the box at Location B then run some queries against the box at Location A to see whether the query result is still as fast as when running locally when at location A or whether its still running slowly. I couldnt swear to it but it sounds like a network issue (possibly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "the first query that is run takes a lot longer than the rest of the
>   queries thereafter."

That's the effect of caching.  The first query pays the toll of physical IO.  Subsequent queries benefit from finding relevant records already in cache, either the DB Buffer Cache or some other OS or architectural buffer.

As for the difference in performance between the two environments, that's probably down to this:

> "roughly 100 miles apart"

It is likely the network connection between the two locations is throttling data transfer.  You need to talk to your network admin, assuming it's a private connection.  If you're using public infrastructure your options are limited.

---

> "seems that End Load is taking the longest of all the methods"

Okay, so I'm not a ASPX expert (I'm here for the [oracle] tag) but some light searching shows up several threads which suggest that it might be "user controls", as [these fire just before the End Load event](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2006/06/30/Complete+Lifecycle+Of+An+ASPNet+Page+And+Controls.aspx).  For instance [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2120653/146325).

Comment: Good call hadn't spotted that bit!

Comment: Well sack 'em and hire someone more knowledgeable.  Seriously.  There's not much some random blokes off the interwebs can do to diagnose problems in *your* infrastructure.  In the meantime I suggest you take up the suggestions @bUKanneer left in the comment.